# Format a cell as arbitrary currency regardless of locale, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

This is really bugging me as it seems pretty illogical the way it's working.

I have a macro to format a cell as a currency using a bit of code to obtain the currency symbol.

Here is the code involved:

```
Dim sym As String
sym = reportConstants(ISOcode)
    'Just use the ISO code if there isn't a symbol available
    If sym = "" Then
    sym = ISOcode
    End If
With range(.Offset(0, 3), .Offset(3, 3))
.NumberFormat = sym & "#,##0;(" & sym & "#,##0)"
Debug.Print sym & "#,##0;(" & sym & "#,##0)"
End With
```

`reportConstants` is a dictionary object with currency symbols defined as strings. E.g. `reportConstants("USD") = "$"`. This is defined earlier in the macro.

When the macro runs it gets the ISO code and should then format the cell with the corresponding currency symbol.

When I run it in one instance the ISO code is "USD" - so `sym` is defined as `"$"` - but it still formats the cell with a pound sign (£). When I `debug.print` the format cell string it shows `$#,##0;($#,##0)` so, as long as I got my syntax correct, it should use a dollar sign in the cell. But it uses a £ sign instead. (I am running a UK version of excel so it may be defaulting to £-sign, but why?)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just recorded a macro to set the format to $xx.xx and it created this: `[$$-409]#,##0.00`. Looks like the -409 localises the currency to a particular country; it works without it - try changing yours to something like `.NumberFormat = "[$" & sym & "]#,##0.00"`

Comment: Thank you MattCrum it seems your method has worked - tested for Euros, pounds and dollars. Weird that one must put a dollar sign in front of the required symbol. E.g. `[$£]` for a pound sign; `[$€]` for a euro sign and `[$$]` for a dollar sign. Post your comment as an answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just recorded a macro to set the format to $xx.xx and it created this: `[$$-409]#,##0.00`. Looks like the -409 localises the currency to a particular country; it works without it - try changing yours to `.NumberFormat = "[$" & sym & "]#,##0.00"`

Answer (score 0):

Btw guess I read your question somewhat after posting ;) Excel is well influenced by the regional settings of your computer for currency, language, dates... Using numberformat can force it to keep the sign you require. if it is a matter of rounding up you can try to: On Excel 2010, go to File - Options - Advanced and scroll down to "When calculating this workbook" and click on the "set precision as displayed" and OK out.

Try this: given your values are numerics/ integers/decimals....

`Range("a2").Style = "Currency"`

Or you can use format:

`Format(value, "Currency")`

`Format(Range(a2).value, "Currency")`

References:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/439331-displaying-currency-based-regional-settings.html

http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-currency-values/

(PS: I am on mobile, you may try these two links)

Comment: I actually want to specify the currency symbol, not just format as a currency. The currency symbol changes depending on the circumstances. My macro seems to work fine for pound and euro signs, but reverts to a pound sign when it should be dollars.

Comment: Second link specifies on both usage to make sure to have desired symbol.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I don't think you understood the nature of my question. The idea is that the cells may contain a number in any currency and I want to format the cell accordingly for different scenarios. I believe MattCrum above solved the issue.

Comment: Well I am glad Matt helped you. When I mentioned, forcing to have the desired symbol that means what you need and what your question is asking, not much of what the title says ;-)